# How to compile only one chapter in the kaobook class

Tags: kaobook

I am starting to the use the kaobook class for a book project. I would like to be able to compile each chapter separately, do you know if this is possible? I could not find a quick solution in the documentation.

Comment: I would assume that the usual include/includeonly mechanism would work.

Comment: Thanks @Teepeemm. I was looking for an option in the class to compile only certain chapters, but actually commenting out the input command for the non-desired chapters makes the job.

Comment: `\include` may work better work for that case, because `\includeonly{chaptersYouWant}` would still let the cross-references work appropriately.